# Unable to display a map marker with a shadow

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-overlay

I'm using a custom `Overlay` class to display a marker on a `MapView` widget. I'm using the same image from another example that I found but my overlay is missing the shadow.

Here's the original:

[image: Here's the original]

..and here's mine:

[image: ..and here's mine:]

How is that shadow created? Is that another drawable resource or some tricks in the `draw` method of the `Overlay` class. Thanks.

--

Here's my `Overlay` class:

```
public class Mappin extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    private final GeoPoint geoPoint;
    private final Context ctxContext;

    public Mappin(Context ctxContext, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        super();

        this.geoPoint = geoPoint;
        this.ctxContext = ctxContext;
    }

    public boolean draw(Canvas canCanvas, MapView mvwMap, boolean booShadow, long lngWhen) {
        super.draw(canCanvas, mvwMap, booShadow);

        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mvwMap.getProjection().toPixels(this.geoPoint, screenPts);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.ctxContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_location_marker);
        canCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x - bmp.getWidth() / 2, screenPts.y - bmp.getHeight(), null);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, its default property. can you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515638/mapview-marker-shadow

Comment: it is not some magical trick. it is up to you to create and put the shadow.

Comment: @Lokesh, I had a look at the link you referred to but I wasn't able to understand what I'm doing wrong. I've posted the code for my `Overlay` class. Could you have a look and see if you see anything wrong there. Thanks.

Comment: Hey make sure booShadow variable is true. If that is false you wont get shadow. Try calling super.draw(canCanvas, mvwMap, true); inside draw method.

Comment: @Kartik, it didn't work.

Comment: @Kartik @Lokesh, the docs for the `Overlay` class's `draw` method say something about shadows but doesn't delve into the details. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20boolean%29

Comment: @Lokesh: Solved it. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code one that displayed the marker shadow. I needed to tweak the skewing factor to get it to work but it did the trick for now. Here's the entire code of my custom `Overlay`:

```
public class Mappin extends Overlay {

    protected Drawable drwMarker;
    protected GeoPoint gptCoordinates;

    public Mappin(Drawable drwMarker, GeoPoint gptCoordinates) {

        this.drwMarker = drwMarker;
        this.gptCoordinates = gptCoordinates;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canCanvas, MapView mapView, boolean booShadow) {

        super.draw(canCanvas, mapView, booShadow);

        Projection prjProjection = mapView.getProjection();

        Integer x;
        Integer y;

        if (!booShadow) {

            x = prjProjection.toPixels(gptCoordinates, null).x - (drwMarker.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2);
            y = prjProjection.toPixels(gptCoordinates, null).y - (drwMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());

        } else {

            Integer intSign = (SHADOW_X_SKEW > 0 ? 1 : -1);
            Float fltScaler = 1.1F - Math.abs(SHADOW_X_SKEW);
            x = (int) (prjProjection.toPixels(gptCoordinates, null).x - (intSign * (drwMarker.getIntrinsicWidth() * fltScaler)));
            y = (int) (prjProjection.toPixels(gptCoordinates, null).y - (drwMarker.getIntrinsicHeight() * SHADOW_Y_SCALE));

        }

        drawAt(canCanvas, drwMarker, x, y, booShadow);

    }

}
```