# Add drop shadow to google map marker android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, shadow

I am implementing google maps sdk, where simply I wanted to show one icon as marker and icon should have drop shadow in circular shape. I am tried so many things from stackoverflow.

Below is function which creates my icons from layout, Layout is having Cardview with elevation.

```
fun generateBitmap(context: Context): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        val mInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        var markerViewBinding = MarkerViewBinding.inflate(mInflater, null)
        val view = markerViewBinding.root

        markerViewBinding.root.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        )


        view.layout(0, 0, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)


        val c = Canvas(bitmap)

        view.draw(c)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Below code is for adding icon to map marker.

```
icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(generateBitmap(context!!)!!)
                val markerOption =
                    MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(icon).zIndex(1.0f).snippet(Gson().toJson(latLng))
                mMap.addMarker(markerOption)
```

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I suggest to achieve this functionality is to create bitmap with shadow and add your icon using that bitmap. You don't need to create canvas icon. I assume you are trying to create similar implementation right ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722035/unable-to-display-a-map-marker-with-a-shadow