# Custom map marker with shadow

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add custom marker on google map v2 within shadow, how to do it?

here is the code I wrote to add the marker:

```
     mapFragment.getMapAsync { map ->
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        markerOptions.position(LatLng(latitude,longitude))
        markerOptions.title("Marker title")
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
        map.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }
```

Comment: Try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515974/3774906

Comment: @rushankshah actually I found this thread before posted my question, but seems they used older version of Google Map. With the MarkerOptions, how can I add the shadow?

Comment: post an image of your marker with shadow you want to add