# How to Create Dynamically numbered Pin Pointers on MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I want to display some locations on my `MapView`. These locations will show pins which will have numbers 1,2,3.. so on(Similar to Google maps result but it is A,B,C..). I think it is not feasible to have pins of all numbers.

Is there any way that i can just create a layout with pin background with `TextView` and I will dynamically put number in `TextView` and that layout ill use as drawable pin??

Or any other method to achieve this?? Please provide some suggestions.

(I am able to show different drawable pins on `MapView`.I just want to create drawables dynamically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this.

Inflated the TextView with pin background and dynamically set the position into TextView.

```
public Drawable createFromView(int positionNumber)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.drawable.pin_icon, null, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pin_background);
    tv.setText("     "+ (positionNumber+1) );   // +1 since position is starting from 0
    tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    tv.layout(0, 0, 50, 50);
    tv.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
    tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: This is really great, just what I've been looking for.  Do you by any chance also have a code snippet for the layout xml file?

Comment: @kfox for R.drawable.pin_icon. It is nothing but a Linear Layout containing one TextView.Linear Layout background is your pin. Just align TextView in center. Let me know if you still need it.I'll provide it to you.

Comment: If R.drawable.pin_icon is a Linear layout with a text view. Does that mean R.id.pin_background is a linear layout containing the pin image?

Comment: @AndrewS Sorry for confusion above- R.drawable.pin_icon is an xml file which has LinearLayout. R.id.pin_background is an TextView in some that LinerLayout whose background is your actual pin image.

Comment: Got it. Great this means I can set the background dynamically and have different colour pins. How I do this is set the background of the TextView to one of several drawable resources via a switch case. Be sure also to ensure that the tv.layout width and height are set to the size of the drawable.  It works well.

Comment: @AndrewS :) I hope your issue is sorted.