# Displaying total number as text for multiple pins with one pin at the same location in map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, text, google-maps-api-3, pins

Displaying total number as text for multiple pins at the same location in map in android

I have 5 images to display on same latitude and longitude.. so I want to give total number as text with one image.. and when I click on that image than display all 5 images in grid view...
so how to display total number as text for multiple pins with the one pin at the same location?

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my question and answer where u can dynamically number your pin's text. Check it and let me know if you need any help.

[How to Create Dynamically numbered Pin Pointers on MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501413/how-to-create-dynamically-numbered-pin-pointers-on-mapview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BadgeView](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) here and add Text over the ImageView and you can update the text of the Badge every time you get the update.

Pseudo code,

```
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(mContext, your_image_view);
badgeViewCart.setText(updated_data);
```

Comment: I am using google map.... so I import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;