# is it possible to have items in a ItemizedOverlay have their own drawables

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

On a mapview when using an ItemizedOverlay is it possible for each item in the itemizedOverlay to have their own drawable? As I have it now I cant get a seperate unique image for each item in the list of items because the marker that you set on the initial creation of the itemizedOverlay is used for every spot drawn on the map. Can you override the constructor or something or will I have to create a list of overlay items I create and populate the map with them.

Comment: your question seems to me same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648482/different-named-markers-on-google-android-map/8379710#8379710

Comment: Yes this following code from that post is what fixed my problem...drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());      Thank you very much :)